# Web shortcut not doing what i want it to do

Tags: python-3.x

So before you question the code, im just trying to learn tkinter a bit more so i though this be best way haha.

I am currently stuck on the web input, everytime i input a website it comes as "https://%21browser.%21text!" and i dont know why. Random web works but it doesnt work as inputting it.

```py
import webbrowser as wb
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes, random, time

class Browser(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        
        global webinput
        
      
        self.title = Label(self, text="Web Shortcut", fg="purple",  font="Kokila 20 bold")
        self.title.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.webinput = Text(self, height=1, width=57)
        self.webinput.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, pady=30, padx=30)

        self.openweb = Button(self, height=2, width=20, text="Open Web", bg="gray", fg="lightgreen", command=self.web)
        self.openweb.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)

        self.random = Button(self, height=2, width=20, text="Random Web", bg="gray", fg="lightgreen", command=self.randomweb)
        self.random.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

        self.exit = Button(self, height=2, width=20, text="Exit", bg="gray", fg="lightgreen", command=exit)
        self.exit.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

    def web(self):
        try:
            self.sites = "https://{}".format(self.webinput)
            if self.sites:
                wb.open(self.sites)

        except Exception as e:
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, str(e), "CRASHED", 0)

    def randomweb(self):
        self.websites = [
            "www.facebook.com",
            "www.google.com",
            "www.youtube.com",
            "www.amazon.co.uk"
        ]

        self.sites = random.choice(self.websites)
        self.visit = "https://{}".format(self.sites)
        wb.open(self.visit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
        
    root.title("Web Shortcut")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.geometry("500x200")

    app = Browser(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some change, now it works very well

```
import webbrowser as wb
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes, random, time

class Browser(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        
        global webinput
      
        self.title = Label(self, text="Web Shortcut", fg="purple",  font="Kokila 20 bold")
        self.title.pack(fill=BOTH)

        self.webinput = Entry(self)
        self.webinput.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, pady=30, padx=30)

        self.openweb = Button(self, height=2, width=20, text="Open Web", bg="gray", fg="lightgreen", command=self.web)
        self.openweb.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10)

        self.random = Button(self, height=2, width=20, text="Random Web", bg="gray", fg="lightgreen", command=self.randomweb)
        self.random.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

        self.exit = Button(self, height=2, width=20, text="Exit", bg="gray", fg="lightgreen", command=exit)
        self.exit.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)

    def web(self):
        try:
            self.sites = f"https://{self.webinput.get()}"
            if self.sites:
                wb.open(self.sites)

        except Exception as e:
            ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, str(e), "CRASHED", 0)

    def randomweb(self):
        self.websites = [
            "www.facebook.com",
            "www.google.com",
            "www.youtube.com",
            "www.amazon.co.uk"
        ]

        self.sites = random.choice(self.websites)
        self.visit = "https://{}".format(self.sites)
        wb.open(self.visit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
        
    root.title("Web Shortcut")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.geometry("500x200")

    app = Browser(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

Hope it helps. (●'◡'●)